# Spring Boot and Hibernate call several time the same method

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, keycloak

I have a weird behaviour with Spring Boot and Hibernate.
I call a method and Spring in some how call it several time.
Here an example of the log on  Tomcat:

```
2018-05-03 15:10:26.661 ERROR 4309 --- [nio-8009-exec-7] i.c.edile.service.api.ApiServiceImpl     : Api Service Get Fattura By Commessa: 248 
.............. 
2018-05-03 15:11:06.468 ERROR 4309 --- [io-8009-exec-10] i.c.edile.service.api.ApiServiceImpl     : Api Service Get Fattura By Commessa: 248 
.............. 
018-05-03 15:11:55.115 ERROR 4309 --- [nio-8009-exec-8] i.c.edile.service.api.ApiServiceImpl     : Api Service Get Fattura By Commessa: 248 
.............. 
2018-05-03 15:11:57.942 ERROR 4309 --- [io-8009-exec-11] i.c.edile.service.api.ApiServiceImpl     : Api Service Get Fattura By Commessa: 248
```

I intercept a request with the following method inside a controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/concludi")
public void concludi() {
    apiService.concludiCommessa();
}
```

This method call a service:

```
@Service("apiService")
public class ApiServiceImpl implements ApiService{

    @Override
    public void concludiCommessa() {

        try {
            for(Commessa c : commessaRepository.findCommessaDaConcludere()) {
                String ftt = keycloakRestTemplate.getForEntity(URL), String.class).getBody();
                if(ftt == null) {
                    continue;
                }
            //........
        } catch (RestClientException | IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Api Service Get Fattura By Commessa: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, for each element that the repository return to the service, I use the KeycloackRestTemplate to make a call towards another web-app.

This is the method inside the controller that intercepts the call using the rest template:

```
@GetMapping(value="/concludiCommessa", params="num", produces="application/json")
    public FatturaCommessaDto concludiCommessa(@RequestParam(value="num", required=true) final String numeroCommessa){
        return fattureService.findByNumeroCommessa(numeroCommessa);
    }
```

This is the method inside the service:

```
@Service(value="fatturaService")
@Transactional
public class FatturaServiceImpl implements FatturaService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="persistenceUnitI24")
    private EntityManager emI24;

    @Override
        public FatturaCommessaDto findByNumeroCommessa(String numeroCommessa) {
            Session session = emI24.unwrap(Session.class);
            FatturaI24 fattureI24 = (FatturaI24) session.createQuery("select f from FatturaRighe r join r.idFatturaI24 f join r.nota n where n.nota like '%"+numeroCommessa+"%'")
             .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
             .uniqueResult();

            //some code
        }
```

The **problem** is that Spring duplicate the call for each element exctrated from the  `apiService`, so after a while Tomcat loses the connectoin witht the DB because there are to many connection.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Do some debugging. What does `commessaRepository.findCommessaDaConcludere()` return? Everything ok there or are you returning dup elements? Then, and this is more related to coding style, I would strongly avoid the `continue` keyword. Code gets much more understandable if you replace it with a simple null check.

Comment: update your codes ..

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.

In my case the problem was Sql Server.. I just increased the memory for query and after that it work perfectly. I also used a repository as @SAM suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you annotate a class as `@Service` and have functions that should be in a Dao class with annotation `@Repository`.

The flow should be: Controller -> Service -> Repository.

Instead of accessing the Db directly from Service class introduce a DAO annotated with @Repository and that should workout.

OR

add annotation `@Repository` to `ApiServiceImpl` . However this is not a good practice.

Comment: Well, I'm using the Entity Manager directly this time, please take a look to my edit.. I added some rows of that service and entity manager.. How can I fix it with the Entity manager?

Comment: I faced this problem before and i did solve the problem like the solution i mentioned.

Comment: introduce a DAO class, this should solve your problem

Comment: you think wrong. I try your solution but don't solve my problem.

Comment: @SAM I have the same problem.. I created a repository interface annotated with `@Repository`, and I also annotated the method inside the service with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` but Spring run it more times... Do you have any another hints?

Comment: I would have gone with the `JpaRepository` if i would have faced so much of issue. try the following approach https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-element-collection-demo/